# How to color bottom in rectuangular 3d box

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost

I got code from this website. I want to fill bottom in 3D magenta color. How to do that?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,fill=magenta,magenta] (0,0) rectangle (12,4.5);
  \draw[thick, fill=white!30] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (12,0) rectangle (11,1) 
    (12,4.5) rectangle node[below=5mm]{$x$}node[left=5mm]{$x$} (11,3.5) (0,4.5) rectangle (1,3.5);
  \draw[semithick, dashed] (1,1) rectangle (11,3.5);
  \draw[thick, {Bar[width=8mm]Latex}-{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] (0,-.5) --node[fill=white]{24} (12,-.5);
  \draw[thick, {Bar[width=8mm]Latex}-{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] (12.5,0) --node[fill=white]{9} (12.5,4.5);
  
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6)}, line join=round]
  \draw[thick,fill=magenta] ([shift={(2,2)}]1,1) rectangle ([shift={(2,2)}]11,2);
  \draw[thick,fill=magenta] (1,1) -- ([shift={(2,2)}]1,1) -- ([shift={(2,2)}]1,2) -- (1,2) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick,fill=magenta] (1,1) rectangle (11,2);
  \draw[thick,fill=magenta] (11,1) -- ([shift={(2,2)}]11,1) --node[right=2.5mm]{$x$} ([shift={(2,2)}]11,2) -- (11,2) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick, {Bar[width=8mm]Latex}-{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] (1,.5) --node[fill=white]{$24-2x$} (11,.5);
  \draw[thick] ([shift={(2,2)}]11,.9)--([shift={(2,2)}]11,.1);
  \draw[thick,magenta, {Latex[slant=1]}-{Latex[slant=1]}] (11,.5) --node[inner sep=0](M){} ([shift={(2,2)}]11,.5);
  \draw[Latex-] (M)--++(1,-1)node[below]{$9-2x$};
  \draw[thick, -{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] ([shift={(2,2)}]11.5,2.5)--([shift={(2,2)}]11.5,2);
  \draw[thick, -{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] ([shift={(2,2)}]11.5,.5)--([shift={(2,2)}]11.5,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the image. I want to color bottom of 3D box.
[image]

Comment: It might be an idea to add an image of what you have now, and the explicitly explain what you need to be colored.

Comment: are you trying to understand your own code? Basically, with 4 vertexes (A), (B), (C), (D) of the bottom, you can fill with `\fill[magenta,opacity=.5] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this you want? (taking into account
Black Mild's suggestion):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,fill=magenta,magenta] (0,0) rectangle (12,4.5);
        \draw[thick, fill=white!30] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (12,0) rectangle (11,1) 
        (12,4.5) rectangle node[below=5mm]{$x$}node[left=5mm]{$x$} (11,3.5) (0,4.5) rectangle (1,3.5);
        \draw[semithick, dashed] (1,1) rectangle (11,3.5);
        \draw[thick, {Bar[width=8mm]Latex}-{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] (0,-.5) --node[fill=white]{24} (12,-.5);
        \draw[thick, {Bar[width=8mm]Latex}-{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] (12.5,0) --node[fill=white]{9} (12.5,4.5);
        
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6)}, line join=round]
            \fill[magenta,opacity=0.6] (3,3) -- (2,2) -- (11,2) -- (12,3) -- cycle; % <<<<< here is the coloring of the bottom you can change color or opacity if you want.
            \draw[thick,fill=magenta] ([shift={(2,2)}]1,1) rectangle ([shift={(2,2)}]11,2);
            \draw[thick,fill=magenta] (1,1) -- ([shift={(2,2)}]1,1) -- ([shift={(2,2)}]1,2) -- (1,2) -- cycle;
            \draw[thick,fill=magenta] (1,1) rectangle (11,2);
            \draw[thick,fill=magenta] (11,1) -- ([shift={(2,2)}]11,1) --node[right=2.5mm]{$x$} ([shift={(2,2)}]11,2) -- (11,2) -- cycle;
            \draw[thick, {Bar[width=8mm]Latex}-{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] (1,.5) --node[fill=white]{$24-2x$} (11,.5);
            \draw[thick] ([shift={(2,2)}]11,.9)--([shift={(2,2)}]11,.1);
            \draw[thick,magenta, {Latex[slant=1]}-{Latex[slant=1]}] (11,.5) --node[inner sep=0](M){} ([shift={(2,2)}]11,.5);
            \draw[Latex-] (M)--++(1,-1)node[below]{$9-2x$};
            \draw[thick, -{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] ([shift={(2,2)}]11.5,2.5)--([shift={(2,2)}]11.5,2);
            \draw[thick, -{{Latex}Bar[width=8mm]}] ([shift={(2,2)}]11.5,.5)--([shift={(2,2)}]11.5,1);
            
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes Thanks. I also followed Black Milds suggestion. But thanks anyways.

Comment: How have you calculated (3,3) -- (2,2) -- (11,2) -- (12,3)? Since I used \fill[opacity=0.3,magenta] (1,1)--([shift={(2,2)}]1,1)-- ([shift={(2,2)}]11,2)--(11,1)--cycle; for bottom.'

Comment: Actually the bottom of the box is defined by some fixed points as (3,3) and some points that are intersecting points of crossing rectangulars as it is (2,2) which is the point that the left side rectangular (its lower side) intersect the front side rectangular (its upper side). Similarly (11,2) is the point that the front side rectangular(upper side) intersect the right side rectangular (its upper side). Finally the point (12,3) is the intersection of back side rectangular (its lower side) with the right side rectangular (its upper side). Hope this helps you to understand how I calculated them

Comment: I calculated the 4 points that exactly define the bottom. You colored a bigger area than that which is covered by the magenta rectangulars of box sides, and it is seen perfectly right if its drawn and filled before the drawing and filling of the magenta rectangulars. Just place the bottom at the end of scope code to see the difference.